# Docker: save internal hd contents

Tags: docker

is there a way to save the contents of a container's "internal" HD. I have tried to use the `docker commit` but when I shut down the container and turn it on again, the contents that I have downloaded or generated inside the container (logs, etc) are gone.

Comment: The `commit` should have worked. Are you running with a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) (`-v`)? If what you are storing is on the volume, that will not be part of the image (but it will still be associated with the container until you `docker rm` the container).

Comment: Nope. The content is inside. I was creating a Nginx server. i had to do the same configuration at least 3 times. Do I need to call the container in a different manner? usually `docker run -i -p XXXX:XXXX -t docker/imagename /bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

When you start the container back up do you use `docker start`  or `docker run`?

`docker run -i -t docker/image /bin/bash` will start a NEW container with the information from the original imagefile.

`docker start {dockercontainerID}` will restart a previously running container. you can get a list of previous dockers with `docker ps -a`

If you have save a docker with `docker commit {runningdocker} docker/image2` you will use the new image name. ie `docker run -ti docker/image2 /bin/bash